# Understanding Spark Streaming WAL failure guarantees

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to understand what will happen when Spark has an exception during processing, especially while streaming.

If I have a small code spinet like this:

```scala
myDStream.foreachRDD { (rdd: RDD[String]) =>
  println(s"processed => [${rdd.collect().toList}]")
  throw new Exception("User exception...")
}
```

If I run this I will get output like this:

```
[info] processed => [List(Item1)]
[error] 28-01-2016 17:41:18 ERROR JobScheduler:96 - Error running job streaming job 1453999278000 ms.0
[error] java.lang.Exception: User exception...
...
[info] processed => [List(Item2)]
[error] 28-01-2016 17:41:19 ERROR JobScheduler:96 - Error running job streaming job 1453999279000 ms.0
[error] java.lang.Exception: User exception...
```

First "Item1" is processed, and it fails (of course).  In the next batch "Item2" is processed.  The record "Item1" has now been lost.

If I change my code so that the exception occurs inside a task:

```scala
myDStream.foreachRDD { (rdd: RDD[String]) =>
  println(s"processed => [${rdd.collect().toList}]")
  rdd.map{case x => throw new Exception("User exception...") }.collect()
}
```

Then the map closure will be retried, but once it has failed enough times the record is discarded and processing continues to the next record.

Is it possible to ensure that records are not discarded, even if this means stopping the application?  I have the WAL enabled.

**Update:** Tathagata Das responded on the Spark User Mailing List [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg44910.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have configured `spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable` to `true`, would also suggest to use `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2` as `StorageLevel` while creating the Stream in your Spark Job, this will ensure that your data is replicated before it is processed further.

I assume that you would also need `EXACTLY_ONCE` semantics in your Streaming job and for that you also need to check and ensure that your receiver is reliable.

Would also suggest to refer **[With Kafka Direct API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#fault-tolerance-semantics)** section for performing transactional updates.

Finally would also suggest to deploy some monitoring tools for watching/ checking Executor logs for any exceptions and when encountered killing the job or taking appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Please see my update and mail chain with T. Das.  Perhaps I could have given a better example.  I don't think the StorageLevel will help, Spark considers the record to have been processed and it will bre removed from the WAL and storage.  At least once is fine, don't need Exactly Once.  I am not using Kafka.  I'm using JMS with no possibility of replay from the source.  Monitoring is good, but by the time the alert has gone off data will already have been lost.